# React native horizontal scrollview does not scroll

Tags: css, react-native, horizontalscrollview

Scroll view does not scroll, only shows first three items, the rest are lost.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView horizontal contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ width: "33%" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child}>
          <Text>B1</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={{ width: "33%" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child}>
          <Text>B2</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={{ width: "33%" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child}>
          <Text>B3</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={{ width: "33%" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child}>
          <Text>B4</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={{ width: "33%" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child}>
          <Text>B5</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
```

Here are the styles I am using

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
container: {
    height: "10%",
    width: "75%",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "lightsteelblue",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    overflow: "hidden",
  },
  child: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

I have already tried several of the solutions offered here on other posts and have not found a solution. Any contructive, good hearted criticism is welcome, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I can able to scroll, I've changed some css's, you can change as per your requirements

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ScrollView horizontal>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child}>
            <Text>B1</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child}>
            <Text>B2</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child}>
            <Text>B3</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child}>
            <Text>B4</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child}>
            <Text>B5</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: '50%',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  child: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snack with your code that works.

https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/horizontal-scroll-working-

Remove that **flexGrow** property and put **width** with respect to the device or a number and don't use percentage there as it was taking the *width* from the **container**.

or simply replace this code with your code.

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView horizontal>
      <View style={{ width: 100 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child}>
          <Text>B1</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={{ width: 100 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child}>
          <Text>B2</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={{ width: 100 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child}>
          <Text>B3</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={{ width: 100 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child}>
          <Text>B4</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={{ width: 100}}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.child}>
          <Text>B5</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
```